# Angular 16: ElementRef error in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: angular

I am rendering a component inside an iframe to print. I have tested it in Firefox, where it works, but a collaborator on the project has pointed out that there are issues in both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

The error I'm getting: *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')*

The code:

```
export class CheckoutComponent {
     @ViewChild('iframe', {read: ElementRef, static: false}) iframe: ElementRef | undefined;
     doc: any;

     onLoad() {
          this.doc = this.iframe!.nativeElement.contentDocument ||this.iframe!.nativeElement.contentWindow;
          this.createComponent();
     }

     createComponent() {
          const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ReceiptComponent);
          component.setInput('order', this.currentOrder);
          component.location.nativeElement.id = 'receipt';
          this.doc.body.appendChild(component.location.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

In the template, it looks like this:

```
<iframe #iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" (load)="onLoad()"></iframe>
```

I am kind of stumped on this since it works in Firefox - I have tried various methods of making it work, but I seem to be getting nowhere. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you waiting for `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: No, but since I only call onLoad once the iframe has been loaded, it should be fine, right?

Comment: Okay, what line throws the error? There's 2 calls to `nativeElement` in your snippet

Comment: It's the first onLoad line where I assign doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome and Explorer dispatch the event load in diferent way than FireFox. I suggest (really I don't like so much) enclosed in a `setTimeout(()=>{...your code})` in the onLoad functions that you have reference to the "iframe" (or check if iframe and if not enclosed by setTimeout

```
   onLoad() {
      if (this.iframe){
          this.doc = this.iframe!.nativeElement.contentDocument ||
                     this.iframe!.nativeElement.contentWindow;
          this.createComponent();
      }
      else  //force to check in a new "cycle"
      {
          setTimeout(()=>{
             this.doc = this.iframe!.nativeElement.contentDocument ||
                        this.iframe!.nativeElement.contentWindow;
             this.createComponent();
          })
      }
  }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much, I was about to rip my own hair out

Comment: @cozybutmessy, and advertisment of my code. There're two different "events": the "ViewChild" and the "load". setTimeout without miliseconds, makes Angular that execute the action after repaint. This is the reason because a ViewChild with `static:false` can be "reach", e.g. in a ngOnInit if enclosed all under a setTimeout. About the event load, I think remember that the event load in Chrome is executed before the "content" is showed, so I'm not pretty sure if change the if by `if (this.iframe && (this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentwindow))` is better